# El método onResume() de mi fragment no actualiza mi adaptador

Tags: java, android, sqlite, recyclerview

**Introducción**: Mi aplicación cuenta de un viewpager con un tablayout dos tabs para ser más específico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que en el boton de + es decir el floating action button inicia una nueva actividad y puedo agregar un registro a SQLITE y al volver mediante el boton de atrás a la actividad principal el fragmento no recarga la lista incluyendo el nuevo registro agregado.

**El siguiente código es el que utilizo para inicializar el recyclerview dentro de mi fragment:**

```
  @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG,"onActivityCreated called");
    //Obtenemos la referencia enviada por parametro en el newInstance
    typeOfFragment = getArguments().getString(TYPE_OF_FRAGMENT);

    //Obtenemos la informacion a mostrar
    notaDAO = new NotaDAO(getActivity());
    List<Nota> notasFromDB = (typeOfFragment != null && typeOfFragment.equals(ConstantUtils.FRAGMENT_TODOS) ? notaDAO.listarNotas() : notaDAO.listarNotasFavoritas());

    //Configuramos la recyclerView donde se mostrara la informacion
    adaptador = new NotaAdapter(notasFromDB, this, getActivity());
    configRecycler(true);
    verificarSiHayMasNotas();

}
```

**A continuación les dejo el onResume() donde trato de actualizar el recyclerview**

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG,"onResume called from "+typeOfFragment);
    final List<Nota> notasFromDB = (typeOfFragment != null && typeOfFragment.equals(ConstantUtils.FRAGMENT_TODOS) ? notaDAO.listarNotas() : notaDAO.listarNotasFavoritas());
    adaptador.addAll(notasFromDB);
}
```

**Y el método addAll de mi adaptador:**

```
  public void addAll(List<Nota> notas) {
    this.notas.clear();
    this.notas.addAll(notas);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

El código de la aplicación entera la dejo en github por si necesitan ver el código completo: [Repositorio de la aplicación GITHUB](https://github.com/zulu15/Help)

Comment: Se está llamando a onResume() cuando volves?

Comment: Si pido disculpas el error era por un problema propio de logica de la aplicacion ya que ocultaba y me olvidaba de volver a hacer visible la recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes que hacer una referencia a tu recyclerview y luego ejecutar el metodo setAdapter() pasandole como parametro el adaptador EJ:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG,"onResume called from "+typeOfFragment);
    final List<Nota> notasFromDB = (typeOfFragment != null && typeOfFragment.equals(ConstantUtils.FRAGMENT_TODOS) ? notaDAO.listarNotas() : notaDAO.listarNotasFavoritas());
    adaptador.addAll(notasFromDB);

    RecyclerView recylcer_view = (RecyclerView)  findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recycler_view.setAdapter(adaptador); 
}
```

Comment: No creo que sea correcto ya que la referencia a mi recyclerview la obtengo en mi metodo onCreateView y luego lleno su adaptado en el metodo onActivityCreated y posteriormente vinculo ambos. Voy a probar lo que dices y luego te comento como me va.